# Delete duplicate rows in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I want to delete duplicate rows in a sqlite database. I found this code online to do it:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
    SELECT min(rowid)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY col1, col2
)
```

But the issue is that my database contains 50+ columns and I don't want to write all the column names in group by. Is there a workaround to group by all the columns?

I am new to this so I may be missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `GROUP BY` clause you must enumerate all the columns.

For your case, I think it's better to create another table `table2` with all the distinct rows of `table1`, then delete all rows of `table1` and finally insert all rows from `table2` to `table1`:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1;
DELETE FROM table1;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2;
DROP TABLE table2;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b4cde3b9bbae9369ce6d4b11d448c475).

Comment: Will this be a good approach considering this table contains around 40k rows and 50+ columns?

Comment: 40k rows is not a large data set neither for group by nor for my proposal.